# UITableView - how to pass-through touches to parent view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have this setup:

```
UIView
  UITableView
  UIView
```

The nested view is hidden initially and I want it to show up when user touches the table view anywhere, on cell, outside section - just about anywhere on the screen outside status/nav. bar. I added touchesBegan for the main view (in which I show the nested view) and when TableView is hidden this works as needed.

When table view is shown, touchesBegan is not called. Thus question is - how to bubble-up the touches to the main view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a hard thing :)

I worked around this by adding one big transparent view on top of the TableView and catch the touches on it. This works in my case, as I don't need to handle touches on the TableView.